# syntax command syntax issue

Tags: stata

I've spent hours reading Stata help file (17SE) but I'm unable to understand why the syntax in this `syntax` command is wrong:

```
syntax, n(integer) interact(real) infage(integer min=45 max=75) supage(integer min=45 max=75)
```

For sure the part until `interact(real)` works, but what's wrong with the following part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you want something more like

```
syntax, n(integer) interact(real) infage(numlist integer >=45 <=75) ///
supage(numlist integer >=45 <=75)
```

There are two points here.

The `min` and `max` arguments  are about how many elements are specified, not about what their values might be. I doubt that you want to insist that the user types in at least 45 integers to each option.

Expecting that a specification `integer()` would support specification of the allowed range seems reasonable enough, but nothing in the documentation supports that. It's `numlist()` that allows more checking.

Comment: Thanks you are right, I forget about the first part. Neverthless 
I tried  >= too, but my main issue was about declaring numlist.

You saved my day.